Salesforce LWC using my own javascript file not working
I built a classic html page with lots of js features and wants to transfer it into Lwc version through uploaded static resource js file,
The uploaded css file as static resource works just fine.
But the js file doesn't work. The js codes have lots of functions with perimeters and none function ones.
1/3. Here is my js file being uploaded:
    let Tag2  = document.querySelector(".myClass2"); 
    let date  = new Date(); 

    document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = "Test 1: " +  date;
    Tag2.innerHTML = myFunction(date);

    function myFunction(dt){    
        dt = "Test 2: " +  dt 
        return dt             
    }

2/3. Here is my html of LWC version:
    <template>
        <lightning-card title="">
            <div class="myClass1">Here to test Css</div-->
            <div    id="myID">    Here is Test 1</div>
            <div class="myClass2">Here is Test 2</div>
        </lightning-card>  
    </template>

3/3. Here is my js of LWC version:
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    import File_CSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/my_file_css' 
    import File_JS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/my_file_js' 
    import {loadScript, loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'

    export default class myPage extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback(){ 
            if(this.isLibLoaded){ 
                return
            } 
            else {      
                Promise.all([
                   loadScript(this, File_JS),               
                    loadStyle(this, File_CSS)                
                ])
                //.then(()=>{ this.setDateOnScreen() }) 
                .catch(error=>{ console.error(error) })

                this.isLibLoaded = true  
            }
        }
    }

I'm hoping to reuse the original js codes as much as possible.
Please help and thanks so much!
